# Calling a function template before and after a more constrained version is defined gives weird results

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

My coworkers showed me following example today:

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrS4BmUlfQAZPLUwAcs4ARpjEINq8AA6oQoTmtHaOLu6kMXFmdL7%2BQU6h4ZFGmCaZtAwEzMQESc6unB7GmKYJ5ZUE2YEhYRG8QhVVNSn1Rv3tfp153ZEAlEaoDsTIHFI6bn7IjlgA1JpuNmi0S1EEQrvYmjIAgqvrm5g7e%2BZ9xJjMTmcX11cEmE5Rqj8HjYCABPKJWN73AAqHyuADdUHh0FsaKgIFDpp9NAB2fRXLYErZ9dAgFDzAhA3Y2HbabScTQAVhstB02l2eOu2IAIljvr9/sxAVTQeDaJCtjC3Od4YjkcFKuitnC2A5MJirjiOYSUag0crHGr2VjubzLgikTq0cTSUJIQB9ZinR70M5bZgOIjqzlawnWskeyl7Gm0xnM1lGjUmjVXPwUpzMPwQL2az7a%2BXECDcbSYtw%2BgmozPZiOcrlSWasaQM%2BSuWTyVDSGwGAxE%2BaLe6rTjyAjSOTTWYAaxAbm0ADoAJwADgn2JkDInDIAbLP5xOVNJuNWe3XpPIhCAZKRu7XZnBYDBEGS/nh2GQKBA0FebyhVOpONoZAeqNefsQ9xBglupDBH4lQgtInakA%2BThWAQADytCsGBtakFg8bqOwgH4C8zRwpge7IZg4hNB6yxyOQ9DFIBrB4MExCgXYWDgV2xB4E4TGzPwjAsBhPB8HQBDCGIkjIUo2gqGoGhNnoKg0XukCzKgxwJPhAC0xK7FyWh6AY75bCpADqbCsHp%2BmEQQdF6eC6BqGYyAqWExAkEIu7FE0pSWNYgx1J41gdLk%2BTKOk8R0F5gWxMFtB%2BV04ScEUJQtKMoWxY0zR0K0VRRZMMUjG0SU5Rl4z%2Bd0nCzEIrZLFw5aVpuyH1lI4gTguKkLtwWwbBJWxviOMjdVsEC4IQJA0m4sVbHYj5hMN2ZjVJuhdlufakAgrxYOESakIObhuCO77Ytw3DTvO2LYto2KrhWUgbqQbEMgeNZkXVu77oeC2kKeF7klEHrkJQD5RNeUyePgRDZZxTBsBwvGcYJEiAQA7nRUTsWuUhVqQ93bis2jDlscOEAgWwNU1LVtS%2BwCdaOPVkUevazMtzCrZQVWXfIN13YBj1GM9NNlgOQ7cDtb4MvUY6cC12gMtwHgXW4NUPTuL3Hm957vRASB/QDt6/agE3hMAnAG3w35hH%2BAHIcBYrEEhEFQTB8GIZhvwSRhyFYW5eC4fhZGEcRPyAbGlHIdRtH0RgywQeZrHI2D3GQ7w0MiLDInKGTKCzTJwRyetimlKp6luJps26QZRkmWZFkqVZNl4HZDlOS58UWBAXh5V4mUBbFQWlHlXcJO3xVxe7aWJfYtTKClpTpWMOTRePI/JN5fRtP3MWleVkPM2jGOkHVRPNa1wDIMgnWcCOnB9QNIPDaN43/Te1/TDN2l6PNx50yt3TrZto7YpOZ0yLSbEwsFwoyumzdGHMFZ7gPDzE8KskCfW%2BneDWT5YqYGBiQZQMcIZcHjvxGGwkyII2YEjKQnZN5y0xh2XG%2BNCaNX3lsQ%2Bx8DZn1frTJaH81rMzASAW6EDapQO5gtPmw4Ry/0OgA06wCUay34fLKQbDeYo20JQneCtYGzFwr%2BBIIBuBAA)</kbd>

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(T)
{
    std::cout << "1\n";
}

template <typename T>
void bar(T value)
{
    foo(value);
}

void foo(std::same_as<int> auto)
{
    std::cout << "2\n";
}
```

Here, `bar(42);` and `foo(42);` print `1` and `2` respectively, **if** you only call one of them.

If you call **both** (in this order), then:

- Clang prints `1` `1`.
- GCC emits a linker error, complaining about multiple definitions of `foo`.
- MSVC prints `2` `2` in release builds and emits a similar linker error in debug builds (could be affected by incremental linking, didn't investigate).

What's going on here? The code looks well-formed to me, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cool. Every compiler is wrong.

Within `bar`, the call to `foo(value)` only has the unconstrained `foo<T>` visible in scope. So when we call `foo(value)`, the only possible candidates are (1) that one (2) whatever argument-dependent lookup finds. Since `T=int` in our example, and `int` has no associated namespaces, (2) is an empty set. As a result, when `bar(42)` calls `foo(42)`, that's the `foo` that is the unconstrained template, which should print 1.

On the other hand, within `main`, `foo(42)` has two different overloads to consider: the constrained one and the unconstrained one. The constrained one is viable, and is more constrained than the unconstrained one, so that's preferred. So from *within `main()`*, `foo(42)` should call the constrained `foo(same_as<int> auto)` which should print 2.

To summarize:

- Clang gets this wrong because it apparently caches the `foo<int>` call and that's incorrect - the other `foo` overload isn't a specialization, it's an overload, it needs to be considered separately.
- gcc gets this right in that the two different `foo` calls call two different `foo` function templates, but gets this wrong in that it mangles both the same so that we end up with a linker error. This is [Itanium ABI #24](https://github.com/itanium-cxx-abi/cxx-abi/issues/24).
- MSVC gets this wrong in that argument-dependent lookup within `bar` for `foo(value)` finds the later-declared `foo`.

More fun is if you change the functions to be `constexpr int` instead of `void`, which lets you verify this behavior at compile time... as in:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
constexpr int foo(T)
{
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr int bar(T value)
{
    return foo(value);
}

constexpr int foo(std::same_as<int> auto)
{
    return 2;
}

static_assert(bar(42) == 1);
static_assert(foo(42) == 2);

int main()
{
    std::cout << bar(42) << '\n';
    std::cout << foo(42) << '\n';
}
```

Then clang compiles (i.e. it does correctly give you that `bar(42) == 1` and `foo(42) == 2` from that spot) but then prints `2` twice anyway.

While gcc still compiles, just having the same linker error because it mangles both function templates the same.

Comment: Also it feels like this should be ill-formed, no diagnostic required... but none of the IFNDR rules seem to apply here.

Comment: Yep, I vaguely remembered this being IFNDR for template specializations, but couldn't find anything for overloads...

Comment: So fixing this would be an ABI-breaking change for constrained functions? I hope it won't stop it from being fixed.

Comment: Barry is there some reason why standard does not require all templates to be defined before first usage? I guess problem is defining/detecting what before means?

Comment: Making this IFNDR would make two-phase lookup almost meaningless - what's the point of limiting ordinary unqualified lookup to the definition context if having a better overload later would make the program IFNDR anyway? After all, pretty much the only case where two-phase lookup matters is when you have a better overload that's not visible from the definition context...